# request for member “ ” in something not a structure or union? in Flex&Bison

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

in my final project left me several codes, one of them is this for flex & bison. The problem is that gcc returns me the message

```
 "error: request for member ‘n’ in something not a structure or union
  141 |  | CONSTANTE {$$=narynew("Constante");}"
```

in bison file ... I do not know how to fix this

---

```c
%{
 #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "parserMiniC.tab.h"
int yylex(void);
void yyerror(char*);


typedef struct node {
    char *type;
    struct node **child;
    int children;
}node_t;


typedef struct _liste_t {  node_t *node;  struct _liste_t *suivant;} liste_t;
liste_t * creer_liste( node_t *p );
liste_t * concatener_listes( liste_t *l1,  liste_t *l2 );
node_t *attacher_liste( liste_t *liste ,node_t *p);

node_t *narynew(char *nom);
node_t *naryattach(node_t *par,node_t *child);
void *naryprint(node_t *par);
bool error_syntaxical=false;
extern unsigned int lineno;
extern bool error_lexical;
%}


%union{ 
node_t *n;
}


%left PLUS MOINS
%left MUL DIV
%left LSHIFT RSHIFT
%left BOR BAND
%left LAND LOR
%nonassoc THEN
%nonassoc ELSE
%left OP
%left REL

%type<n> expression fonction variable
%type<liste> instruction liste_instructions parm liste_parms

%token<n> CONSTANTE
%token IDENTIFICATEUR  VOID INT FOR WHILE IF ELSE SWITCH CASE DEFAULT
%token BREAK RETURN PLUS MOINS MUL DIV LSHIFT RSHIFT BAND BOR LAND LOR LT GT 
%token GEQ LEQ EQ NEQ NOT EXTERN

%start programme
%%

programme:  
        liste_declarations liste_fonctions
;
liste_declarations  :   
        liste_declarations declaration 
    |   
;
liste_fonctions:    
        liste_fonctions fonction
|fonction 
;
declaration:    
        type liste_declarateurs ';'
;
liste_declarateurs: 
        liste_declarateurs ',' declarateur
    |   declarateur
;
declarateur:    
        IDENTIFICATEUR
    |   declarateur '[' CONSTANTE ']'
;
fonction:   
        type IDENTIFICATEUR '(' liste_parms ')' '{' liste_declarations liste_instructions '}'
    |   EXTERN type IDENTIFICATEUR '(' liste_parms ')' ';'
    
;
type:   
        VOID
    |   INT
;
liste_parms:    
        liste_parms ',' parm 
    |   parm
    
;
parm:   
        INT IDENTIFICATEUR 
;
liste_instructions :    
        liste_instructions instruction 
    |instruction 
;
instruction:    
        iteration
    |   selection
    |   saut
    |   affectation ';'
    |   bloc
    |   appel
;
iteration:  
        FOR '(' affectation ';' condition ';' affectation ')' instruction
    |   WHILE '(' condition ')' instruction
;
selection:  
        IF '(' condition ')' instruction %prec THEN
    |   IF '(' condition ')' instruction ELSE instruction
    |   SWITCH '(' expression ')' instruction
    |   CASE CONSTANTE ':' instruction
    |   DEFAULT ':' instruction
;
saut:   
        BREAK ';'
    |   RETURN ';'
    |   RETURN expression ';'
;
affectation:    
        variable '=' expression
;
bloc:   
        '{' liste_declarations liste_instructions '}'
;
appel:  
        IDENTIFICATEUR '(' liste_expressions ')' ';'
;
variable:   
        IDENTIFICATEUR
    |   variable '[' expression ']'
;
expression: 
        '(' expression ')'
    |   expression binary_op expression %prec OP
    |   MOINS expression
    |   CONSTANTE {$$=narynew("Constante");}
    |   variable  {$$=narynew("Variable");}
    |   IDENTIFICATEUR '(' liste_expressions ')'
;
liste_expressions:  
        liste_expressions ',' expression
    | expression
    |
;
condition:  
        NOT '(' condition ')'
    |   condition binary_rel condition %prec REL
    |   '(' condition ')'
    |   expression binary_comp expression
;
binary_op:  
        PLUS
    |   MOINS
    |   MUL
    |   DIV
    |   LSHIFT
    |   RSHIFT
    |   BAND
    |   BOR
;
binary_rel: 
        LAND
    |   LOR
;
binary_comp:    
        LT
    |   GT
    |   GEQ
    |   LEQ
    |   EQ
    |   NEQ
;
%%

int main(void){
    printf("Debut de l'analyse syntaxique :\n");
    yyparse();
    printf("Fin de l'analyse !\n"); 
    printf("Resultat :\n");
   

   
naryprint(root);


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
void yyerror(char *s) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur de syntaxe a la ligne %d: %s\n", lineno, s);
}






// tree  fonctions ...

void *naryprint(node_t *par)
{
    size_t cldidx;
    node_t *cld;
    node_t *match;

    match = NULL;

    for (cldidx = 0;  cldidx < par->children;  ++cldidx) {
        cld = par->child[cldidx];
        if (cld == NULL)
            continue;
        printf("%s --> %s  \n",par->type,cld->type);
        }

        for (cldidx = 0;  cldidx < par->children;  ++cldidx) {
        cld = par->child[cldidx];
        if (cld == NULL)
            continue;
          naryprint(cld);
        }
    }


// narynew -- get new node
node_t *narynew(char *nom)
{
    node_t *node;

    node = calloc(1,sizeof(node_t));
    node->children=0;
    node->type=nom;
    return node;
}

// naryattach -- attach new child node

node_t *naryattach(node_t *par,node_t *child)
{
    size_t cldidx;
    node_t *cld;

    // increase size of array
    cldidx = par->children++;
    par->child = realloc(par->child,sizeof(node_t *) * par->children);

    // allocate new node
    cld = child;

    // cross-link parent and child
    par->child[cldidx] = cld;
       printf("%s  est attaché \n",cld->type);

    return par;
}



liste_t *creer_liste( node_t *p ) { 
     liste_t *liste;
    liste = (liste_t *) malloc(sizeof( liste_t ));  
     liste->node = p;
       liste->suivant = NULL;
         return liste;}

liste_t * concatener_listes( liste_t *l1,  liste_t *l2 ) {
      liste_t *l = l1;
        if ( l1 == NULL )
    return l2;
      while ( l->suivant != NULL )  
        l = l->suivant;
        l->suivant = l2;
        return l1;
        }

node_t *attacher_liste( liste_t *liste,node_t *p ) {
      liste_t *l;
      node_t *n;
        for ( l = liste; l != NULL; l = l->suivant ) {
            n=l->node;
           naryattach(p,n); 
            }
            return p;
            }
```

Comment: If that is not the problem, please paste into your question the complete text of all the compilation errors produced, and also the bison version number.

Comment: it was the probelem ,,,thank youuuu :)